# Null Pointer Exception in LayoutInflater

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I have made Bean class in which we get & set values for name & image and make two other class .
   i made `MainActivity` class and `ListAdapterPlay` class, in which i want to set images in listView item .
    But it give `NullPointerException` in `LayoutInflater`

```
public class ListAdapterPlay extends BaseAdapter {
// private Bean bean;
private ArrayList<Bean> objarraylist;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater objlayoutinflater;

public ListAdapterPlay(ArrayList<Bean> objarraylist, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.objarraylist = objarraylist;
    objlayoutinflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); //error at this line 
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Bean bean = (Bean) getItem(position);
    convertView = objlayoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewrow,null);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    // bean= new Bean();
    txt.setText(bean.getName());

    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    String uri = "drawable/" + bean.getImage();
    int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null,
            context.getPackageName());
    Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    img.setImageDrawable(image);
    // img.setBackgroundResource()

    return convertView;
}
}
```

i made `MainActivity` class as below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayList<Bean> objarraylist;
private  ListAdapterPlay objlistadapter;
private ListView listview;
private Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    objarraylist=new ArrayList<Bean>();
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","ic_launcher"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));
    objarraylist.add(new Bean("RAM","lion"));

    objlistadapter= new ListAdapterPlay(objarraylist,context);
    listview=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    listview.setAdapter(objlistadapter);
}

}
```

i want to set images in listView item but it through `NullPointerException` in `ListAdapterPlay` class.
  error is at this line

```
objlayoutinflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I am stuck at this situation why? It give `NullPointerException`?

Comment: In which line you get null pointer exception in ListAdapterPlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ListAdapterPlay(ArrayList<Bean> objarraylist, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.objarraylist = objarraylist;
    objlayoutinflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); //error at this line 
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

**May be the context is null**

```
objlistadapter= new ListAdapterPlay(objarraylist,context);
```

while constructing the `ListAdapterPlay`

try

```
objlistadapter= new ListAdapterPlay(objarraylist,this);
```